# DataTables.js - show/hide column when input's value is between 2 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to create external (next to DataTable table) input where user can enter `zipCode`.
When `zipCode` is between value of two columns (`zip code from` and `zip code to`) then show, otherwise hide the row.

my input and table are simple

```
<input id="zipCode_" class="input100 hidden-password" type="search" name="zipCode_">

<table id="table_zipCodes">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Zone name</th>
    <th>zip code from</th>
    <th>zip code to</th>
    <th>description</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>10-100</td>
        <td>20-100</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>30-200</td>
        <td>30-300</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    [...]
</tbody>
```

and my script:

```
var table = $('#table_zipCodes').DataTable({
             orderCellsTop: true,
             fixedHeader  : true,
            'paging'     : false
})

$('#zipCode_').on('keyup', function(event) {
            var new_zipCode = $(this).val();

            if (zipCode_value.length === 6) {
                
                table.rows().every(function() {      // <-- *i tried* table.rows(function(){
                    var this_row = this.data();
                    var col_from = this_row[1];
                    var col_to   = this_row[2];
                    console.log(this_row);     // <-- result below
                    console.log(this.child);   // <-- result below

                    if (new_zipCode >= col_from && new_zipCode <= col_to) {
                        table.row(this).child().show();    // i<-- no reaction like below with hide()
                    }
                    else {
                        // I TRIED
                        //table.row(this).child().hide();  <- no reaction
                        //this.child.hide().draw();   <- no reaction
                        // this.hide()  <- error "this.hide is not a function"
                    }
                });

                table.draw();
            }
        });
```

result from: `console.log (this_row);` as expected: one single row:

```
(4) ["first", "10-100", "20-100", "test"]
    0: "first"
    1: "10-100"
    2: "20-100"
    3: "test"
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

result from: `console.log(this.child)`:

```
ƒ (){var d=b.apply(a,arguments);x.extend(d,
d,c.methodExt);return d}
```

The problem is, when i want to hide/show specific row it doesn't do anything. I read about external search with dataTable or search range but i want 'range' from one input and search two columns like so: `if (new_zipCode >= col_from && new_zipCode <= col_to)`.
After two days I just give up... I can't solve it :(

Comment: Have you looked at this example?  It sounds like exactly what you need? https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: I think i checked it but i'll try it again. Give me a second :)

Comment: @user12031119 ok, something is changing. I think now I have to get around to the "if" condition because it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help mr @user12031119

Maybe somebody will need it so i'll write the answer:

my script looks like:

```
var table = $('#table_zipCodes').DataTable({
         orderCellsTop: true,
         fixedHeader  : true,
        'paging'     : false
})

$('#zipCode_').on('keyup change paste', function() {
    table.draw();
}

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var col_from      = data[1];   // data from second column (`zipCode from`)
    var col_to        = data[2];   // data from third column (`zipCode to`)
    var zipCode_value = $('#zipCode_').val();    // data from input

    var new_zipCode = zipCode_value;    

    if (zipCode_value.length > 2) {
        if (new_zipCode.length < 6) {      
            // if length of input is not complete add regex wich will find everything to the end (it's like `like` in sql ( ... WHERE a LIKE 'string%'
            var matcher = new RegExp(new_zipCode + '*');
            if(matcher.test(col_from))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else {
            // show only exact matching row
            if (new_zipCode >= col_from && new_zipCode <= col_to) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;   // remove not maching row
        }
    }
    else
        return true;   // show everything

}
);
```

i tried to comment the code as much as i could. I hope I helped someone :)